# red 5 recorder app set up

Tags: linux, centos-6, red5

Does anyone know how to set up this Red5 Recorder application on Red5 1 RC2 for Linux CentOS 6.4?

I followed set up of WEB-INF folder from this document http://fms.denniehoopingarner.com/newapp.html

I can get to the swf mysite.net:5080/red5recorder/bin-debug  but it is getting error because stuck in local rtmp url and looking in red5recorder.html there doesn't seem to be anywhere to input my url for rtmp. The installer just flashes and disappears.

I don't see how even if I can edit URL, how I can get directory structure correct so it opens in red5recorder folder like the other apps in webapps folder.

I need to use the installer provided but it just, as I said before, flashes and then goes.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few recorder implementations out there for red5. If you are using the one offered here: http://www.red5-recorder.com/ then the rtmp url is a parameter you pass to the swf in your page; the parameter details are here: http://www.red5-recorder.com/params.php